# Proof verification: Weak induction implies Strong induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I am self-studying Calculus by Spivak and there it is implied that weak induction and strong induction are logically equivalent. I have seen the other proofs on the website that this is indeed the case, but I have had trouble translating the proofs into intuition. Therefore, I wanted to write the proof in my own words so that I can make sense of it. However, I do not know if the work I have done is actually valid, hence this post. Could you validate my proof?

My proof:
Assume that we are able to show $P(1)$ holds and $P(n+1)$ holds whenever $P(n)$ holds, so $P(n)$ holds $\forall n$. Let $Q(n)$ be the statement that $P(1),...,P(n)$ holds, clearly $Q(1)$ holds as $P(1)$ holds. Now further assume that $Q(n)$ holds, we want to show that $Q(n+1)$ also holds. Since $Q(n)$ holds then $P(1),...,P(n)$ holds so $P(n+1)$ also holds and $Q(n+1)$ holds. Therefore by ordinary induction $Q(n)$ holds $\forall n$.

Comment: Your proof is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that your proof is okay.  However, I would have stated it differently, to explain **why** the **weaker** premise of *weak induction* yields the same result as the **stronger** premise of *strong induction*.

Both tools, weak induction and strong induction start the same.  That is, they both prove that a statement, like $P(n)$ is true in a baseline case.  For example, often, they will both prove that $P(1)$ is true.

Then, weak induction then proves that 
$P(N) \implies P(N+1)$ 
while strong induction then proves that 
$\{ ~P(1) ~\wedge~ P(2) ~\wedge~ P(3) ~\wedge~ \cdots  ~\wedge~P(N) ~\} \implies P(N+1).$

The point is that the weaker premise of weak induction can be seen to imply the stronger premise of strong induction.

That is, using the premise of $P(r) \implies P(r+1)$ you have that

$$P(1) \implies P(2) \implies P(3) \implies \cdots \implies P(N).$$

So, the weaker premise of weak induction allows the stronger premise of strong induction to be fulfilled.  This explains *why* weak and strong induction yield the same result.